# Writing json data to file on interval and reading on new line with Node.js filesystem

Tags: javascript, node.js

Every x amount of seconds i want to write (log) some data in json format to a file. (e.g `{timestamp: new Date(), data: "somedata"}`)
If a new line (a new object of data in json format) has been written to the file, i want to read the last line of the file and console log that.
How would i achieve this with the Node.js filesystem?

Comment: what does last line means if you have a json file? does it mean you want the last key value pair?

Comment: It would basically be the last, most recent object - my winston setup for example logs a json object per line. (thats what i meant with last line)
Proper json format would obviously be an array of objects, but i am not sure if there is a way/how i would actually select the last item. (just via pop(), maybe?)   
My biggest question is just if there is a way to write to a file and somehow listen for changes in the file?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use mongodb with mongoose for saving your logs. There is an example for you.

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    inventoryDetails: Schema.Types.Mixed
});

// catching every save
schema.post('save', (doc) => {
  console.log('%s has been saved', doc._id);
});

var Log = mongoose.model('Log', schema);

setInterval(() => {
    // create data log
    Log.create({ data: { any: 'thing'} }, (err, small) => {
        if (err) throw Error(err);
        // saved!
    });
},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be like this:

```
import fs from 'fs'

const ws = fs.createWriteStream("./test.txt", { flags: 'a' })

let writeToFile = {
    timestamp: new Date(),
    data: "somedata"
}

const i = setInterval(() => {
    ws.write(JSON.stringify(writeToFile), (err) => console.log(`wrote ${JSON.stringify(writeToFile)} to file`))
}, 1000)

process.stdin.resume()
```

important is the 2nd argument `{flags:'a'}`, which sets that you append to the file. You could also go for `fs.appendfile()`